# Replace using Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I need to find and replace specific text within text file (It is a subtitle file). I'm using Notepad++ for it.

Here's a sample:

```
1 
10:00:12,042 --> 10:00:15,959 
This is text.

2 
10:00:17,542 --> 10:00:21,709 
This is another text
```

I want to find and replace whenever there is new line and carriage return (\n\r) followed by '10:*' and replace it with '00:*'

```
1 
00:00:12,042 --> 10:00:15,959 
This is text.

2 
00:00:17,542 --> 10:00:21,709 
This is another text
```

Can you please suggest regex I should use in Notepad++ Find&Replace dialog?

I've tried using:

```
\n\r10:
```

But keep getting 'Can't find text "\n\r10:"'

Comment: Ok, thanks.
I've tried few things. Should I edit post or put it as a comment?

Comment: Are you sure there are LFCR endings? Not CRLF? Try `\r\n10:` (and select *Extended* search mode)

Comment: Wow, thanks Wiktor. This resolved my issue

Comment: @haf.o.matic: You have an answer from Sven, I think you can accept that one.

Comment: @Wiktor Thanks, I will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for `^10:` and replace it with `00:`

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning: *and select **Regular Expression** Search Mode*. `^` in Notepad++ matches the beginning of a line, so this should work.

Answer (score 2):

Select `Search Mode > Regular Expression`

Find What : `^10`

Replace With : `00`

Comment: Oh, a real "bot". Copying others' answers :)

Comment: I did find the answer but was not fast enough :(

Comment: Then, you do not have to duplicate answers. That is what I do, unless I see some specific difference, or added value in my answer. Please add something to stand out. Note that this +1 from Alexandar is a point in credit.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew He was probably writing it while the other answer was posted and didn't see it. I don't think he deliberately posted a duplicate answer

Comment: And this answer is the only one mentioning `Search Mode > Regular Expression` within the answer

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Exactly there was no answer when I was writing this. I didn't want to duplicate on purpose.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck: I do not deny that it is probably like that. I just suggest adding something so that this answer does not sound the same. Thomas, OP select the tag Regex, I guess OP already selected that. Adding that `^` matches the line start would be really welcome. A link to regex anchors in Notepad++ would be also great.